Sofascore scraping goal times
I have Excel 2019 and Python 3.12.4. For Football results from Denmark, Superligaan, season 2022/2023 I would like to see the goal times. My Python code gets goal times of a match. But I would like all games in a season of the Danish league (date, home team, away team, result and goal times). Everything should be inserted into Excel.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

# Define the headers
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# Scraping the main page (although this part is not used later in the code)
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.sofascore.com/fc-midtjylland-brondby-if/GAsOA#id:12174728',
    headers=headers
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Get pregame form data
response_form = requests.get('https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/12174728/pregame-form', headers=headers)
form = response_form.json()

# Get incidents data
response_incidents = requests.get('https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/12174728/incidents', headers=headers)
incidents = response_incidents.json()
incidents = incidents['incidents']
incidents_df = pd.json_normalize(incidents)

# Filter goal incidents
goals_df = incidents_df[incidents_df['incidentType'] == 'goal'].loc[:, ['time']]


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
output_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sofascore_data.xlsx')
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    goals_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Goals', index=False)


print(f'Data has been written to {output_file}')

I noticed that the hit times are not correct.

can you share what you have tried so far? and an example of the expected output

Here's an update to the previous code to get both past and future games:
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
import time

def get_matches(tournament_id, season_id, path):
   base_url = f'https://www.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/{tournament_id}/season/{season_id}'

   # check if tournament has any past/future matches
   if requests.head(f'{base_url}/events/{path}/0').status_code != 200:
      return []

   result = []
   i = 0
   hasNextPage = True
   while hasNextPage:
      url = f'{base_url}/events/{path}/{i}'
      response = requests.get(url)
      data = response.json()
      hasNextPage = data.get('hasNextPage')
      result.extend(data.get('events', []))
      i += 1

   return result


def get_all_events(tournament_id, season_id):
   past_matches = get_matches(tournament_id, season_id, 'last')
   future_matches = get_matches(tournament_id, season_id, 'next')

   # sort past matches by date (future matches already sorted)
   past_matches.sort(key=lambda x: x['startTimestamp'])

   return  past_matches + future_matches
   


def get_match_incidents(event_id):
   url = f'https://www.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/{event_id}/incidents'
   response = requests.get(url)
   data = response.json()
   return data.get('incidents', [])


def main():
   tournament_id = 649
   season_id = 58388
   matches = get_all_events(tournament_id, season_id)

   data = []
   for match in matches:
      incidents = get_match_incidents(match['id'])
      data.append([
         match['tournament']['name'],
         match['homeTeam']['name'],
         match['homeScore'].get('current'),
         match['awayTeam']['name'], 
         match['awayScore'].get('current'),
         time.strftime('%x %X', time.localtime(int(match['startTimestamp']))),
         match['status']['description'],
         ', '.join( f"{i['time']}'" for i in incidents if i['incidentType'] == 'goal')
      ])

   headers = ['Tournament', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Start Date', 'Status', 'Goal Times']

   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
   df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()


Notes:

Code might be very slow (many requests), look into async/multithreading if you want to improve speed.
tournament_id and season_id were taken from the sofascore web url.


Preliminary result: good
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


def get_all_events(tournament_id, season_id):
    result = []
    i = 0
    hasNextPage = True
    while hasNextPage:
        url = f'https://www.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/{tournament_id}/season/{season_id}/events/last/{i}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        hasNextPage = data.get('hasNextPage')
        result.extend(reversed(data.get('events', [])))
        i += 1

    return result


def get_match_incidents(event_id):
    url = f'https://www.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/{event_id}/incidents'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data.get('incidents', [])


def convert_to_berlin_time(timestamp):
    # Convert timestamp to datetime object
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

    # Define Berlin timezone
    berlin_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')

    # Convert datetime to Berlin time
    dt_berlin = dt.astimezone(berlin_tz)

    # Format as string
    return dt_berlin.strftime('%x %X')


def process_match(match):
    incidents = get_match_incidents(match['id'])
    return [
        match['tournament']['name'],
        match['homeTeam']['name'],
        match['homeScore']['current'],
        match['awayTeam']['name'],
        match['awayScore']['current'],
        convert_to_berlin_time(int(match['startTimestamp'])),
        ', '.join(f"{i['time']}'" for i in incidents if i['incidentType'] == 'goal')
    ]


def main():
    tournament_id = 39
    season_id = 41914

    data = []
    matches = get_all_events(tournament_id, season_id)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(process_match, matches)
        for result in results:
            data.append(result)

    tournament_name = 'Dänemark'
    season_name = str(season_id)  # In diesem Beispiel wird die Season-ID als Teil des Dateinamens verwendet
    filename = f"{tournament_name}_{season_name}.xlsx"

    headers = ['Tournament', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Start Date', 'Goal Times']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    df.to_excel(filename, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

